# Which OpenID Connect provider to choose? (with password reminders out of the box)

Tags: open-source, password-manager, user-management, openid

Which open source OpenID Connect self-hosted servers do support advanced features like password reminders, Facebook authentication, etc. out of the box? I also need the ability to control them programmatically (via an API).

Python, PHP, C# (worse), Java, or other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you will not find some package out there that is going to provide you all these capabilities and features you are asking. However, I recommend you to take a look at some of the recommended libraries, for Python and JavaScript, below, for implementing an OpenID Connect provider:

- **Python**: `Authlib`, `OAuthlib` (Django OAuth Toolkit, if you are willing to use Django) & `django-oidc-provider`
- **JavaScript (Node.js)**: `node-oidc-provider`

> I advise you to check also some of OAuth2.0 libraries for implementing an OAuth2.0 authorization server, such as oauth2orize (with oauth2orize-openid) and node-oauth20-provider. Remember that OpenID Connect (OIDC) is a thin layer on top of the OAuth2.0 protocol
>
> I recommend you visiting: https://openid.net/developers/certified/, for finding Certified OpenID Connect Providers for every coding language!

I hope that helps, please let me know if you have any more questions